# When extracting an ISO, it warns of low disk space, but I have 15 gigs at least. No idea what to do

Tags: 12.04, usb, iso, ram, extract

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I tried bleachbit, tweak, and all sorts of things. I removed old kernels, orphan files, cleared cache, just almost everything you can think of. I deleted programs, and games I don't even use. I'm trying to extract a windows 8 ISO, and put the files on a bootable USB stick. No matter what I do, nothing works. After a few minutes it'll warn of low disk space, and it'll stop.

When I run `mount` it gives

```
/dev/loop0 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda2 on /host type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096)
gvfs-fuse-daemon on /home/mastershadow/.gvfs type fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=mastershadow)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/43845E1D0505BFD7 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda5 on /media/01CE2F72C1774740 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda3 on /media/PRESARIO_RP type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)
/dev/sda1 on /media/3C066EC0066E7B32 type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)>
```

WHen I run `df-h` I get

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on

```
/dev/loop0      9.3G  2.7G  6.1G  31% /
udev            742M  4.0K  742M   1% /dev
tmpfs           301M  872K  300M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            751M  156K  750M   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda2        26G   11G   16G  41% /host
/dev/sdb1        15G   65M   15G   1% /media/43845E1D0505BFD7
/dev/sda5       7.9M  3.9M  4.0M  50% /media/01CE2F72C1774740
/dev/sda3       4.1G   54M  4.0G   2% /media/PRESARIO_RP
/dev/sda1        62G   60G  2.6G  96% /media/3C066EC0066E7B32
```

Comment: Can you run `mount` and check if /tmp or /var/tmp are mounted as tmpfs rather than on-disk?

Comment: What program are you using to extract the ISO, and where are you extracting it to?

Comment: I'm just extracting it by right click, and "extract here". I was going to manually put the files onto my USB drive.

Comment: @K7AAY I'm trying extract the Windows8 ISO.

Comment: can you run `df -h` and paste the output

Comment: did you installed ubuntu via wubi?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest obtaining the MD5 or SHA-1 hash of the install disc from the [My Digital Life website](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/43813-Windows-8-Pro-Retail-Box-Hashes-%28SHA-1%29/page2?s=67ad364c57579e955d201694df073297), and [compare it to your download with the Microsoft utility](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533) to make sure the download was good. If it was corrupted, you could get what you report.

Should that prove to match, then I would extract just a portion at a time with an archive manager, which works for me. Just open the ISO file with an archive manager and dig down to file what you need within the ISO then extract it.